# jqgrid editable x number formating is inconsisent with format on grid

Tags: jqgrid

I've built a grid as the code bellow:

```
colModel: [
            { name: 'price',
              label: 'price',
              index: 'price',
              jsonmap: 'price',
              formatter: 'number', 
              formatoptions: {decimalSeparator:",", thousandsSeparator: ".", decimalPlaces: 2, defaultValue: '0,00'},
              editable: true
            }
          ]
```

The format of field is correctly on grid, for instance: 10,32, but the form created to edit the field fills one with 10.32 instead of 10,32.

Someone knows why this is going on? Do I need to use properties as edittype and editoptions (this one using formmater and formatoptions) as well? if yes, How I need set up these properties?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've fixed the problem using the the function `afterShowForm` to handle the formating of field on form generated from grid.

In fact, I was expecting that `jQGrid` could do that automatically, i.e, using the configuration provided to column to apply on field generated, or if i could apply the configurion on `JSON` message, for instance:

```
editoptons: { formatter = "number", formatteroptions = { .... } ...
```

anyway, it's working now.